# MySQL Full Text Search not returing all records

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

First time implementing Full Text Search...

I've run the necessary ALTER TABLE SQL to enable FULLTEXT on the applicable tables/fields.

On the following beta site: http://wtc.betaforming.com/

If I do a search for "leadership", I get normal results except for the Events section at the bottom.  I have Events with that word in the event title and throughout the description copy (http://wtc.betaforming.com/events/event/?event_id=10039).

If I do a search for "communications", I get results in the Events section, which makes me think I have everything configured correctly.

I'm using the following basic code for testing purposes:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblevents
WHERE MATCH(event_title, event_desc_long, event_desc_short, event_tab_one_title, event_tab_one_text, event_tab_two_title, event_tab_two_text, event_tab_three_title, event_tab_three_text, event_tab_four_title, event_tab_four_text) AGAINST ('$site_search_term')
```

This is the same code I'm using to search Products and Articles (changing the necessary FROM and WHERE information).

Not sure what is happening (since it works for some phrases) or where to start looking in my db to see what is wrong.

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

My search term was over the 50% threshold - you have to read all the way to the bottom to find this.

I've implemented the "IN BOOLEAN MODE" for my events search and everything appears to be working correctly.  I also used this article for help:

http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/